# Possible downsides of working parttime due to project

Tags: software-industry, part-time, netherlands

I have been working at my current company for almost a year now. Things are going well and I'm happy working there. I am now on a temporary contract (1 year) but this is ending soon and I expect they'll hire me for indefinite time.

Now, besides work, I have this side project that has some potential. Several parties have already expressed their interest and while this is of course no guarantee, I would like to try and get it to the market (and of course hope it 'takes off' :) ) But, I don't have a lot of time to work on this, next to my fulltime job and volunteering.

I was thinking about the possibility to work parttime (80% - 4 days) to finish my project in the day that I am off, but I do not want to kill my 'career'. Ideally, of course, I can make enough money with my project later and I quit my job altogether but this is not something I forsee for the direct future (like, next year or so).

What are the downsides to going from fulltime to parttime job for this kind of reason? Does the reason even matter? I don't want to become a manager or something, but I also don't want to be the 'part-time employee' that gets left out of every opportunity.

For context, I'm a software developer living in The Netherlands

Comment: You may want to check if your contract allows for this. In some cases you have to notify or even ask for permission (the last usually only if the project is potentially a conflict of interest / competing with your employer).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I already checked that, it's not a problem. My manager knows about it. Besides, it has absolutely zero overlap with my work, the customers we have or the code I write :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a lead developer for several developers here in The Netherlands, this sounds both perfectly fine and perfectly normal.

The guy sitting right behind me right now does not work Friday's. Friday's he works for his own company (ZZP). I myself work on several open source projects of my own design and several as yet closed source. Because I can.

There's really nothing wrong with working for yourself besides having a job. Just make sure that your (future) employer knows about this beforehand so they don't get the surprise when you two sit down for the contract.

Seeing [the shortage of developers (NL)](https://tweakers.net/nieuws/137631/uwv-helft-ict-vacatures-is-moeilijk-invulbaar.html) in Holland at the moment you could go and give it a positive spin. Such as:

- This is also beneficial to the job as doing so I also learn about X
- Volunteering here next to my job and my personal projects also teachers me Y and Z

Seriously, look at the positive. Any employer wants assertive people, like yourself, on his/her team because they're able to offer a multitude of different insights and skills.

Comment: In the Netherlands I feel like working 4 days a week is so normal for lots of people for lots of different reasons ('papadag', studying, teachers etc.) that I think it's almost weird to call it part-time. I leave that for anything below 4 days.